# Find files with 32 character long recursively in a directory and apply a command

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, ls, mogrify

I have folders and files looks likes this:

```
/thumbs/6b0/6b029aab9ca00329cd28fd792ecf90a.jpg
/thumbs/6b0/6b029aab9ca00329cd28fd792ecf90a-s.jpg
/thumbs/d11/d11e15a72e20e14c45bd2769d763126d.jpg
/thumbs/d11/d11e15a72e20e14c45bd2769d763126d-s.jpg
```

And I want to apply following command to the files not have -s in their names in all sub directories in thumbs folder.

```
mogrify -resize 50% -quality 85 -strip filename.jpg
```

I have look around find and grep but couldn't figure out how can I do this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused which files you want to match exactly - in one case you appear to have 32 hex digits plus the .jpg suffix, and in another 33 hex digits plus the suffix (each with and without the -s). Should both the non -s files match, or only the 32 digit one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find thumbs/ -not -name "*-s.jpg" -exec mogrify -resize 50% -quality 85 -strip {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but it gives me following errors:
root@test /home/test/assets/thumbs/test # find . -not -name "*-s.jpg" -exec mogrify -resize 50% -quality 85 -strip {} \;

mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `.' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `./f1' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `./f2' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.

Comment: Sorry, It is working though, thank you!

Comment: Replace `-not` with `!` to make it standard/portable.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the subject:

```
find . -name '????????????????????????????????.jpg' -exec cmd {} \;
```

To insert those 32 `?`s, with `tcsh`, `zsh` or `bash` in `emacs` mode, type <kbd>Alt+3</kbd><kbd>Alt+2</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>. With those shells and `ksh` in `vi` mode, enter a `?`, leave the insert mode with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then press <kbd>x</kbd> to cut that `?`, and then `32p` to paste it 32 times.

With GNU `find`, you can also do:

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*/[^/]{32}\.jpg' -exec cmd {} \;
```